# What is this shrub with clumps of small white flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

Last year I started redoing all the front landscaping at my house. At the time, I didn't know this bush flowered, but I moved it to the back to let it grow. What is it?

*click on picture for full size*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Viburnum plicatum; when in flower, often mistaken for Hydrangea anomala, but the leaves are not the same. Grows well in sun or partial shade, average height and spread 2.5 to 4 metres.https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/94896/Viburnum-plicatum-f-tomentosum-Mariesii/Details

Comment: Your answer implies that height and width are approximately the same. However, one of the main characteristics of this viburnum is that it has horizontal habit - width Is always significantly larger than its height.

Comment: https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/94896/Viburnum-plicatum-f-tomentosum-Mariesii/Details

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c0/75/ce/c075ce5c25d4730d5a6da71e6b77aec2--dream-garden-shrubs.jpg